# Append a row that has a linked text to a Google Sheet | Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to append a row that has a clickable element to a Google Sheet.

I tried using RichText but it only creates cells that have "RichTextValue".

[image: Current output]

Here is my current code:

```
function addCourseLink(course) {
  var courseCode = course.slice(0, 3) + "-" + course.slice(3, course.length)
  var richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText('Visit this website')
    .setLinkUrl(`https://url.com/${courseCode}/`)
    .build();
  return richText
}

function createRows(averages) {
  const rows = [];
  for (const semester in averages) {
    const courseGrades = averages[semester];
    for (const course in courseGrades) {
      const grade = courseGrades[course];
      rows.push([addCourseLink(course), semester, grade]);
    }
  }
  return rows;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to create a cell that contains a hyperlink you can literally pass the formula, no need to include richText, please try this:

```
function addCourseLink(course) {
 const courseCode = course.slice(0, 3) + "-" + course.slice(3, course.length)
 const text = ('Visit this website');
 const hyperlink = `=HYPERLINK("https://url.com/${courseCode}/","${text}")`;
 return hyperlink;
}
```